# Error occuring when installing Visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I had already installed VS 2008 in my Laptop.When i starts installing vs_vstsweb.exe(Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2010 Team Suite Beta 1 - ENU) after first three steps it got stopped.So i decied to uninstall full vs 2008 and uninstalled .now when i  installing vs 2008 its getting error

---

```
                  Visual studio just-in-time debugger
```

**An unhandled exception (system.io.filenotfoundException) occured in ServiceModelReg.exe[2760].Just-In-Time debugging this exception
failed with the following error:No installed debugger has Just-In-Time 
debugginh enabled.In visual Studio,Just-In-Time can be enabled from 
Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time**

Could you please guide me how to i recover from this error.
I also tired With this [tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968856.aspx)

Still same error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point it's possible the machine is still in a bad state from the VS 2010 Beta1 failed install.  AFAIK, there is currently no uninstall tool available for VS 2010.  But you can follow the steps outlined in that link.  For every program which is listed as 3.5, remove the component also if it's labeled as 4.0.